# return срабатывает раньше img.onload?

Tags: javascript, массивы, функции, promise

Мне нужно перевести черно-белое изображения в вектор, состоящий из 1 и 0
Написал функцию, которая принимает на вход путь к файлу и возвращает массив из 1 и 0.

```
function readImg(file) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, draw.width, draw.height);
    var img = new Image(),
        convert = [];
    img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var imgdata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, draw.width, draw.height).data;
        for (var i = 0; i < img.width * img.height; i++) {
            if (imgdata[i*4] > 0)
                convert.push(0);
            else
                convert.push(1);
        }
    }
    img.src = file;
    return convert;
}
```

Но вот проблема, если я пытаюсь дальше работать с этим массивом, то его как бы не существует. К примеру:

```
var temp = readImg("img.png");
console.log(temp.length) //Выведет "0"
```

Получается, что массив `convert` возвращается пустым и не успевает заполнится, т.к. функция `img.onload` еще не выполнилась.

**UPD:** Прочитал про Promise, попытался прикрутить его к моему коду

```
function readImg(file) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, draw.width, draw.height);
        var img = new Image(),
            convert = [];
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            var imgdata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, draw.width, draw.height).data;
            for (var i = 0; i < img.width * img.height; i++) {
                if (imgdata[i*4] > 0)
                    convert.push(0);
                else
                    convert.push(1);
            }
            resolve(convert);
        }
        img.src = file;
    });
}
```

Теперь использую эту функцию так

```
readImg("img.png").then(function (result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Результат выводит правильный, но как мне этот `result` присвоить другой переменной и использовать дальше? Я хочу использовать это так:

```
data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    data[i] = [];
    readImg(i + 1 + ".png").then(function (result) {
        data[i][0] = result; //ошибка Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined
    });
}
```

Comment: Да, язык javascript содержит очень много асинхронного кода, [используйте обещания (promise)](https://learn.javascript.ru/promise)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема. Когда функция выполняется внутри Promise значение внешней переменной i будет другим и его напрямую использовать нельзя. Я передал его как параметр.

Только у меня здесь одна и та же картинка для примера.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var draw = new Object();
draw.width = ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
draw.height = ctx.canvas.clientHeight;

function readImg(file,num) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, draw.width, draw.height);
        var img = new Image(),
            convert = [];
        var myresult = new Object();
        myresult.num=num;
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
        img.onload = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
            var imgdata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, draw.width, draw.height).data;
            for (var i = 0; i < img.width * img.height; i++) {
                if (imgdata[i*4] > 0)
                    convert.push(0);
                else
                    convert.push(1);
            }
            myresult.convert=convert;
            resolve(myresult);
        }
        img.src = file;
    });
}

data = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    readImg("https://i.imgur.com/K38QcUh.png",i).then(function (myresult) {
        local_i=myresult.num;
        data[local_i] = [];
        data[local_i].push(myresult.convert);
        // или data[local_i]=myresult.convert;
        alert(data[local_i]);
    });
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="5" height="5" class="playable-canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Спасибо за пример. Это немного приблизило меня к правильному решению, но не до конца. Если я работаю как-то с переменной data дальше, то есть в самом конце вне циклов и функция я пытаюсь её вывести(например) её все еще не существует. Вывод console.log(data.length) в самом конце даст 0.

Comment: Конечно. Чтобы работать с data дальше нужно ждать пока обработаются изображения.

Comment: Я понимаю, но как это сделать? Я же не буду засовывать весь код, который в дальнейшем работает с data в функцию-обработчик resolve

Answer (score 1):

Ну тогда проще сделать так. Вызываем загрузку изображений одной функцией передавая ей список файлов для загрузки. После загрузки первого изображения вызывается загрузка второго и тд. После последнего запускается функция nextcode туда и пишите остальной код.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var data = [];
var draw = new Object();
draw.width = ctx.canvas.clientWidth;
draw.height = ctx.canvas.clientHeight;

function readImgList(imglist) {
        ctx.clearRect(0, 0, draw.width, draw.height);
        var img = new Image();
        img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous"; //это нужно только для примера тк изображение загружается с другого домена
        var k=0;
        img.onload = function() {
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
        var imgdata = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, draw.width, draw.height).data;
        data[k]=[];
        for (var i = 0; i < img.width * img.height; i++) {
            if (imgdata[i*4] > 0)
              data[k].push(0);
            else
              data[k].push(1);
            }
            if (k+1<imglist.length) {
              k=k+1;
              img.src=imglist[k];
            } else {
              nextcode();
            }
        }
        img.src = imglist[0];
}

var imglist = [];
imglist[0] = "https://i.imgur.com/K38QcUh.png";
imglist[1] = "https://i.imgur.com/K38QcUh.png";
imglist[2] = "https://i.imgur.com/K38QcUh.png";
readImgList(imglist);

function nextcode() {
  console.log(data);
  //и сюда пишете весь ваш остальной код
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="5" height="5" class="playable-canvas"></canvas>
```